# Open USB host communication on a device already connected at the launch of the application

Tags: android, usb, host

I'm developping an application and I need to manage a device using the usb host mode of my tablette.

At this point, I could only activate the USB, at the connection of the device.
Process step :

1. No application launch, connection of the device.
2. Android ask me if I wan't to launch my application
3. I accept
   Then the application start, and I could use the USB connection.

But, it is not that I want to do :

1. Tablet off, connect the device
2. switch tablet on
3. Launch manualy the application
4. Initialise the usb connection with the device.

The fact is, that actualy, I need to unconnect/connect manualy the usb on my tablet to have the connection, but me, in my case, the device will be already connected to the tablet, then i need to initialise the connection without unconnect/reconnect the usb.

I have tryed the example provided by Google on the USB Host connexion page that speak about Broadcast receiver, but that don't work, or I don't understant it very well.

My questions is:
Is there any method to open the connection to an usb host device, that is already connected ?

By witch way I need to search to find this dammed solution :D

Here the code that is already implemented to help at understand my problem :

manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/..." 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >

        <activity
            android:name="...Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The file res/xml/device_filter.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="5455" product-id="8238" />
</resources>
```

Then the onResume() in my Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {

        UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

    } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
    }
}
```

And at the end my method that allow to make the connection :

```
protected void open(Object o) throws DeviceException {
    if (device != null && device.getVendorId() == 5455 && device.getProductId() == 8238) {
        int nbEndPoint = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
            UsbInterface usbInterface = device.getInterface(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
                UsbEndpoint usbEndPoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(j);
                nbEndPoint++;
                switch (nbEndPoint) {
                case 1:
                    this.pipeWriteData = usbEndPoint;
                case 2:
                    this.pipeReadCommandResult = usbEndPoint;
                case 3:
                    this.pipeReadAutoStatus = usbEndPoint;
                case 4:
                    this.pipeReadImageData = usbEndPoint;
                }
            }
        }

        usbConnection = manager.openDevice(device);
        if (usbConnection == null || !usbConnection.claimInterface(device.getInterface(0), true)) {
            usbConnection = null;
            throw new DeviceException(DeviceException.UNKNOW_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with the accessory mode. I think putting `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the manifest fixed it. Try that for starters and I'll try to remember how I fixed the problem, it may help with USB host as well.

Comment: That `launchMode` goes in your `<activity>` tag by the way.

Comment: @TronicZomB Have you fixed your problem ?

Comment: It was adding the `singleTask` to the manifest that fixed this for me. I just checked it again and it works.

Comment: @MonkeyJLuffy do you try to write code at USB client that communicate with USBHost application at both end Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're app probably establish the communication with a listener that looks for a connection just being made of the USB device. If the printer is already connected and your app is waiting on that listener, it will not happen since your call back function will not be called, the usb printer already being there before your app is running. This is a guess since I did not see your code but I saw that kind of behavior for that reason in other cases.

EDIT after getting more info in the question. 
As I said in my comment, i believe the event lauching your app (the ...USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED) is not happenning if the device is already connected at boot time. To prove that, you should add a lot of traces with [logcat (viewing)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) and [(writing)](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)in your code, inside your onCreate, onResume and may be elsewhere.  Do that and you will see if each section perform what you expect. My guess is it's not executed at all when you boot and the USB device is already connected. 
If I understand what you want is this. When the device is being connected, you want to launch you app. But if the device is already there at boot time, you want your app to be launched anyway and connect to the USB. The way I would approach this is by having you app looking for the presence of the targeted USB device. The presence is different than the "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" which means it just got connected in the last few milliseconds. I would also register a listener on "USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" that would launch your code on device connection and I would set also a listener on "BOOT_COMPLETED" to launch your app after your tablet booting sequence.

Comment: I don't understand precisely your answer :/. Could you explain me about the listener that you seak about ?

Comment: In your first case when it works, it's because you registered a listener to the event of this USB device getting connected. This listener is launching your app on the occurance of that event and you make the connection. It's the same as when you want your app to be launch at boot time, you set-up a listener on "BOOT_COMPLETE". In your case, you have set it on the connection of that USB device. But, nothing prevents you from launching it manually and it should work. Look at the detail of what happen in the code triggered by the listener. It will show you how to establish the connection

Comment: Here you are my code. Please, could you explain "But, nothing prevents you from launching it manually and it should work.". Because we try it, without succes. Maybe is the way to made it that it wrong. (Do you speack french ?)

Comment: Yes I speak french but it's better to keep going in english since most of the planet uses english for technology and business and the answers given here should help others. If you look at your manifest, you are having an intent filter looking like ...USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED. So, in my opinion, your app is called and everything is structured to happen on the event of a USB device getting attached to the USB. If it's already attached, the event of ...USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED is not happening. ... I will add to my previous answer to have more characters.